# Web Api Routing nightmare. Can't make it work for all Controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC Web Api RESTful service. I am not using API version 2.

I created a Controller with the default GET/POST/PUT/DELETE. Everything was fine until I decided to add some more functionality to my controller.

Long story short, I ended up with near a dozen route templates (very nasty WebApiConfig file) for my controller. It was working fine until.... i needed a second controller. Then the chaos began.

All the routes for the DocumentController obviously didn't work for CompanyController because what I had previously configured was just a bunch of crappy patches to make my first Controller work. Here I am four days after and still can't get it to work. I truly can't grasp my head around this whole routing thing. So complicated and inflexible (in my opinion).

Here is some code for you to understand.

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"This is GET");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Metadata()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"This is Metadata");
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is GET with ID");
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] DocumentDTO document)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is Post");
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] DocumentDTO document)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is PUT");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Tags(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is GET TAGS");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Tags(int id, [FromBody] IEnumerable<TagDefinitionDTO> tagDefinitions)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is POST TAGS");
    }
}
```

So, my initial dream was to achieve the following

GET `/document/` => ALL DOCUMENTS

GET `/document/3` => Document Id=3

POST `/document/` => CREATE A DOCUMENT

PUT `/document/3` => EDIT A DOCUMENT

GET `/document/metadata` => RETURNS GENERAL CONFIGURATION FOR ALL DOCS

GET `/document/6/tags` => GETS ALL TAGS FOR DOCUMENT ID=6

POST `/document/6/tags` => CREATES TAGS FOR DOCUMENT ID=6

I don't even post the WebApi because it's quite embarrassing. Like I said, I was able to make it work with the extra methods but it was almost a one to one mapping to my controller/actions. AWFUL... I know.

When I added a second Controller.... obviously... Mission Impossible.

Now, don't want you to think I haven't done some research (i've used constraints, defaults, etc., etc., to not avail... pitiful). Once I get one Controller to work, the other breaks.

I get all sorts of errors. From "more than one method for GET" to "Resource Not Found", "method now allowed POST".

Here I am, five days later going in circles. This is extremely frustrating.

QUESTION.

Has anyone faced these issues? Is the routing deal SO limiting that you can only have those 4 operations per control? Should I create a route template PER action in my controller, meaning that if I have 10 controllers with 10 actions I should add 100 route templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answer from Yishai, I think changing your routes to the following should work for your scenario:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Default" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d*" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { action = @"[a-zA-Z]+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi3",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+", action = @"[a-zA-Z]+" }
);
```

Then on your default actions place an ActionName attribute.

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Default")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"This is GET");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Metadata()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"This is Metadata");
    }

    [ActionName("Default")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is GET with ID");
    }

    [ActionName("Default")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] DocumentDTO document)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is Post");
    }

    [ActionName("Default")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] DocumentDTO document)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is PUT");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Tags(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is GET TAGS");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Tags(int id, [FromBody] IEnumerable<TagDefinitionDTO> tagDefinitions)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is POST TAGS");
    }
}
```

As mentioned, Web API 2 is a much better way to go.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. So, what I've learned so far is that your action="Default" basically "routes" the call to those 4 methods (since the actual method name "filters" the call type [get/post/put/delete])... so, in the dictionary there will be 4 Default entries... etc. Thanks and also thanks to Yishai who started the "brainstorm" process!

Comment: IT STOPPED WORKING! :(.... LORD HAVE MERCY!!! It stopped working for requests like http://url.com/documents.... it says. "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly."

Comment: I was tracing. I don't think the call actually makes it to webservice. I have a class inheriting from DelegatingHandler (I check security) and nothing happens when I just call url.com/documents. I have to actually add an action to the call for this class to be called, ex. url.com/documents/metadata. (this is the first class called even before any controller in the pipe). 

Any idea what could've happened here?

Comment: only if I explicitly type url.com/document/Default it works. Otherwise it says 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: If your controller is called documentcontroller then your url should contain 'document' and not 'documents'. i.e. url.com/document

Comment: I think the regex in the first route may have been incorrect. Change the id = @"\d+" to id = @"\d*". I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, switch to using attribute routing.

Then on each action or controller you can just put the route template.

OR the following routes should work for you

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi3",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

Comment: I can't use the attribute routing. I am using API v.1, not v.2. I am going to try your suggestion and I will let you know!

Comment: Sure - There is also the attribute routing library for Web API V1 by Tim McCall `Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi`

Comment: "Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get()" I am getting this error with your config. Let me take a look at that package.

Comment: My bad, this should only work with Attribute Routing. I would seriously consider updating to Web API 2 if you can. The only limitation would be that you have to run on .NET 4.5